# Como formatar a data para o padrão brasileiro em um atributo do tipo "DATEONLY" utilizando sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, sequelize-js

Eu possuo uma model com um atributo date do tipo DATEONLY, quando eu passo no corpo da requisição 01/02/1999, e o retorno é "date": "1999-01-02". Como posso formatar para o padrão brasileiro?

```
    date:{
    type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
    allowNull: false
    
},
```

Answer (score -2):

Uma boa maneira de vc fazer isso para formatar data é utilizar o moment.js.
Exemplos em https://momentjs.com/;

date = moment(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY") as any;

Comment: Moment.js foi [descontinuado](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/) o fabricante alerta para que que a biblioteca não seja utilizada em novos projetos.